# python nose tests: is it possible to run a subset of tests

Tags: python, testing

I'm using nose for testing some REST API written using Flask. Also I'm using script-manager. Everytime I do `manage test` it'll run through all the tests. This is OK for CI but not ideal if one wants to fix something. In golang, there is a way to specify a subset of test to run by providing a regexp. Is there something similar in nose?

Answer (score 2):

You can run
`nosetests -m REGEX`
as specified in nose's [options page](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html#options).

Comment: Could you give some example?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need full regex you can also specify a path with grobs after `nosetests`, e.g.:

```
nosetests tests/my_cool_subset*
```